# Axios doesn't give neither .then or .catch response after POST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to do a post in a localhost SQL DB with react/nodejs. Fortunately it does POST and the information goes to the DB. I wanted to put an alert() inside the .then() if it was sucessfull and another alert() inside the catch() if there was a error. The problem is that it gives both 'success' alert and 'error' alert when posting, although it posts all good in the database. Am I missing something?

```
  const submitForm = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert',{
    manager:manager,
    decisionDate:decisionDate.toLocaleDateString(),

    }).then(alert('Success'))
    .catch(alert('Failure'))
  }
```

Comment: You're calling alert twice immediately, then passing the _results_ as "callbacks".

Comment: How to fix your typo: CHange `alert('Success')` to `alert.bind(undefined, 'Success')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not right which results in an error that is then caught by `catch` clause.

Update the callback to be the following:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert', {
    manager:manager,
    decisionDate:decisionDate.toLocaleDateString(),
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log('Success', response);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Please refer to [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect for the `then` callback, which results in an error that is then caught by `catch`. Update the callback to be the following:

```js
  const submitForm = () => {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/insert',{
    manager:manager,
    decisionDate:decisionDate.toLocaleDateString(),

    }).then(() => alert('Success'))
    .catch(() => alert('Failure'))
  }
```

Comment: I've changed the code as you said but neither .then() and .catch() alert anything but the POST keeps being successfull. I've tried with console.log() instead of alert but the result is the same.

Comment: Your environment may not support arrow syntax `() => {}`. You can use function syntax instead `.then(function () { alert('Success' })`